# How to break after response in Play (Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to Play Framework using Scala. I want to evaluate a condition and in that condition evaluates to true, I want to send a response and exit at that point. However, the code below that I am trying continues till the end.

I tried breaking with a `return` statement - However, I get a type mismatch. Can someone help me out with this?

```
def hello = Action { request =>

    if (true) {
      Ok("in If")

      // Return at this point
    }

    print("This line should not be printed")
    Ok("final") 
}
```

***EDIT***

Assume a GET call is being made with 4 parameters - `name`, `age`, `married`, `spouse`. I want to make sure all 3 params (`name`, `age`, `married`) are passed in, and if `married` is true, check if `spouse` is passed in. If this validation fails, I want to respond saying `Bad Request`. Else, continue with logic. How do I write this?

Comment: I did think of that - The problem is with multiple conditions and large code blocks. That would result in large pieces of code inside the else block. For example, imagine I was checking the request parameters - there would be 3-4 if-else combinations as a result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435800/explicit-return-from-play-action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative way to do it:

```
case class QueryInput(name: String, age: Int, married: Boolean, spouse: Option[String]) {
  def validated = if(married && spouse.isEmpty) None else Some(this)
}

def validateInput(request: RequestHeader) = {
  val input = for {
    name <- request.queryString.get("name").flatMap(_.headOption)
    age  <- request.queryString.get("age").flatMap(_.headOption.flatMap(a=>Try(a.toInt).toOption))
    married <- request.queryString.get("married").flatMap(_.headOption.map(_=="true"))
  } yield {
    QueryInput(name, age, married, request.queryString.get("spouse").flatMap(_.headOption))
  }

  input.flatMap(_.validated)
}

def hello() = Action { request =>
  validateInput(request) match {
    case Some(input) => Ok(input.toString())
    case None => BadRequest
  }
}
```

In fact, there are many options. You could also play with the Either class to do validation: Left value to accumulate errors and return bad request, right value to construct your validated input.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to have a method for validating the parameters. Then do a simple if/else to check if the parameters are valid and return a success or a general error.

If you really want a specific

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, by putting a return Ok in but really, thats not the scala way.  What you want to do is to change your mindset and imagine everything as a function.  If you didnt know, if-then-else always returns a value.  For example, you can actually write if this way:

```
def hello = Action { request =>
  val result = if (true) {
    Ok("foo")
  } else {
    Ok("bar")
  }

  result
}
```

of course, an even more scala way is to use matchers

```
def hello = Action { request =>
  val result = true match {
    case true => Ok("foo")
    case _ => Ok("bar")
  }

  result
}
```

Take that one step further and you dont even need to specify the result object at all, because scala figures out the returning object based on the last object returned/created.

```
def hello = Action { request =>
  true match {
    case true => Ok("foo")
    case _ => Ok("bar")
  }
}
```

EDIT: TO answer the OP's edit, you still want to use the matcher.  Assuming your vals are options, heres what you do:

```
def hello(nameOpt:Option[String], ageOpt:Option[String], marriedOpt:Option[String]) = Action { request =>
  (nameOpt, ageOpt, marriedOpt) match {
    case (Some(name), Some(age), Some(married)) => Ok("all 3 are given")
    case (Some(name), Some(age), _) => Ok("all 2 are given")
    // functionally same as above
    // case (Some(name), Some(age), None) => Ok("all 2 are given") 

    // some combination of the above
    case (None, None, Some(married)) => Ok("married but no name or age")

    // default case
    case _ => Ok("bar")
  }
}
```

Comment: 'True' is just an example. Imagine a request query is passing 4 parameters. I want to make sure all 4 exist, and do some other conditional checks. Only if all 4 were correct, I will proceed to business logic - Otherwise I want to break in the beginning. IF-ELSE blocks means that entire large chunks of code reside in these blocks which I want to avoid

Comment: I have added an Edit, could you please provide a simple code example?

Comment: Although I like @critium solution, I was typing my own answer at the same time; you now have two alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

First thing:

> When the block evaluates, all of its expressions and declarations are processed in order, and then the block returns the value of the last expression as its own value.

Second: [don't use return](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html).

And the third one is a Play Framework way of resolving your problem: [action composition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaActionsComposition). Though I would not say that it is trivial.

Comment: I have added an Edit, could you please provide a simple code example?